# deRham complex via Cech complex?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6193v1.pdf), in the proof of Theorem 4.10 on page 11, the following claim is made.  Let $F$ be a polynomial $A$-algebra, and $B = F/I$ a quotient ring.  Then, the completion of the de Rham complex $\Omega^\bullet_{F/A}$ along the ideal $I$ is quasi-isomorphic to the Cech complex for the map $A \rightarrow F$ completed along the kernels of the maps $F \otimes_A F \otimes_A \cdots \otimes_A F \rightarrow B$.

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5001v1.pdf) is referenced, and I suspect that the argument should be somewhere in Notation 2.1 or Remark 2.5, but I'm having trouble parsing through the topos theory language.

Does anyone know a reference to this result, or can anyone explain it?  Thanks!